# Can Pandas export a .csv with column-specific quoting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

OSX 10.9.2
Python 3.3.4
Pandas 0.13.1
csv 1.0

I'm using Pandas to manipulate a `.csv` which I then hope to export *back* to csv using the `.to_csv()` function, so that others can open it in various spreadsheeting apps. However, the quoting is messing everything up. The issue is that one of my columns will be a hyperlink in the spreadsheet app (Numbers.app 3.1 on OSX 10.9.2), which uses the format `=hyperlink("URL", "Link Text")`; `pd.to_csv()` defaults to `quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`, which tries to quote the `"` in the hyperlink, which messes up Numbers.app.

Using `quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE` produces errors about `escapechar` not being set; setting `escapechar = '|'` (or whatever character), results in `Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set` regardless.

### For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Boring column', '=hyperlink("http://stackoverflow.com", "Exciting column"']])
df.to_csv('fake.csv')

!cat fake.csv
# ,0,1
# 0,Boring column,"=hyperlink(""http://stackoverflow.com"", ""Exciting column"""

import csv
df.to_csv('fake.csv', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
# Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

df.to_csv('fake.csv', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = "^")
# Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

Even if I could get `csv.QUOTE_NONE` to work, there are a few columns that could use some `QUOTE_MINIMAL`. Ideally, I could just set the quoting on a per-column basis. Is there any way to do that?

I suppose my best alternative will be a few loops and some manual writing with `csv.writer` or perhaps just good old fashioned `writelines()`. Just seems like a shame -- so far I think Pandas is *fantastic*, it seems like there would be an eaiser way to do this.

### EDIT:

I thought I had cleverly avoided the problem by using:

```
df.to_csv('fake.csv'), quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep = '\t')

with open('fake.csv', 'r') as r:
    lines = [line.replace('\t', ',') for line in r.readlines()]

with open('fake.csv', 'w') as w:
    w.writelines(lines)
```

Unfortunately this (as it should) leaves *everything* unquoted, including the `,` in some of the columns and in `=hyperlink("URL", "text")`, which inappropriately splits these cells. Also tried using `quotechar = "'"`, which unfortunately appears to do nothing at all (apparently only a keyword for `pd.read_csv()`).

### Workaround 1: Google Drive

Unfortunately, looks like it may just be a problem with `Numbers.app`'s interpretation of the quoted cells; the `.csv` file uploads to Google Drive appropriately, and if re-downloaded as an excel file opens properly in `Numbers.app`.

### Workaround 2: Export to Excel

The Google Drive trick made me realize this might. work. And it does. First, `pip3 install xlrd xlwt-future`. Then: `df.to_excel('fake.xls')`. Opens in Numbers just like I'd hoped, simple as that.

Comment: How about just import the data w/o the column headers.  Manipulate the data, and then export back.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question.  I was thinking the column header was a hyperlink.  You're saying the entire column are hyperlinks.

Comment: Ah, I see. Correct, the column itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my edit above, looks like it was an issue with `Numbers.app`'s handling of quoted cells, and not the cells themselves.

My solution:

1. `pip3 install xlrd xlwt-future`
2. `df.to_excel('fake.xls')`
3. Open in Numbers

However, if anyone has a way to do per-column quoting rules in Pandas, I'll still mark that as the correct answer, since that was my original question.